# Can Kendall Tau/Spearmann correlation and Multiple Linear Regression be used together? it is continuous data in which IVs are not normally distributed

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, kendall-tau

I have one dependent variable and 3 main Independent variables (the 1st IV has 7 factors that are scored individually, thus, making it 9 Independent variables). I want to see the correlation between the variables and check for significant predictors. My Dependent variable and its residuals follow a normal distribution and all other assumptions for multiple linear regression are met. My independent variables are not normally distributed, hence, I cannot use parametric test for correlation, but, by default, Linear regression runs Pearson's correlation. So, should I run Kendall/Spearmann separately to see the correlation and then run multiple linear regression? Or should I use log10 to convert my independent variables to normal and then run regression including pearson correlation?

P.S. my sample size is 130, and the variables are related to clinical psychology

Comment: did you ever get the answer for this? im stuck in the same boat.

Comment: It's possible this is a similar question: [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/572633/can-i-use-a-kendalls-tau-in-place-of-a-pearsons-correlation-and-then-do-a-multip](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/572633/can-i-use-a-kendalls-tau-in-place-of-a-pearsons-correlation-and-then-do-a-multip)